# Cron expression for the second to last day of week of the month

Tags: java, cron, quartz-scheduler, crontrigger

I want to trigger the second to last day of week of the month.

Typically, here is the last friday of the month (ex : 30/06/2017)

```
0 0 0 ? * FRIL
```

And I want the second to last (ex : 23/06/2017)

```
0 0 0 ? * FRIL-1
```

But this syntax return the same result as before (with the Quartz scheduler and with [cronmaker](http://www.cronmaker.com/))

The second to last day of week of the month can appear either the 3rd or the 4th week of the month.
So it's :

```
either : 0 0 0 ? * FRI#3 
or     : 0 0 0 ? * FRI#4
```

Do you have any advice ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can express that using cron syntax.
I can think of some work-arounds, though:

- You could schedule your job every Friday and have some in-job logic to check whether it is actually the second-to-last before going on.
- Another option would be to create a dummy cron trigger for the last Friday, retrieve the "next fire time", substract 7 days from that date and create the actual trigger using that exact date -- but you'd have to do that for every week (either by pre-scheduling several triggers, or by having your job re-schedule itself after each run).